# How can i use binary Serialization for a List<objects>

Tags: c#, serialization

```
public class profile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CameraInfo { get; set; }
    // And many other properties describing the Profile Class
}
```

i have a list of objects of the same class List channels=new List()
and there is string that holds the file name. i have put both into a dictionary:

```
 Dictionary<string, List<profile>> DChannelList = new Dictionary<string, List<profile>>();
```

So every time user creates a new profile i want to append it into the same file. And distinguish each with the filename. What kind of serialization is suggested?

Comment: Zip seems like a good format.

Comment: mostly planning to use Binary serialization...could you help me with that

Comment: Sounds like you got it all figured out.  No need for this question.

Comment: But i dunno how can i use it...i have worked with xml serialization but this looks complicated...could you giva me an example?

Comment: No.  That's not what your question asks.  Also, we don't write code here on SO.  We fix your broken code.  So write some broken code and ask a question you want an answer to.